# Sql query with punctuation marks

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

I have a webServer Between my SQL database and my Android app. On the database I want to put a sentence with question marks but when the webserver catches the query, the echo is null. This only happen when I use question marks, dots or commas in the phrase. 
The code of the webserver is:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="*****";
$database_localhost ="*****";
$username_localhost ="*****";
$password_localhost ="*****";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$resultado = mysql_query('SELECT pregunta,respuesta,intentos,frase FROM Frases');
if (!$resultado) {
    die('Consulta no válida: ' . mysql_error());
}

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $pregunta = $fila['pregunta'];
    $respuesta = $fila['respuesta'];
    $intentos = $fila['intentos'];
    $frase = $fila['frase'];

}

mysql_close($localhost);

$data = array('pregunta' => $pregunta, 'respuesta' => $respuesta, 'intentos' => $intentos, 'frase' => $frase); 
print (json_encode($data));

?>
```

Comment: I think something got lost in translation. What do you mean by 'interrogations'?

Comment: He probably meant question marks, I don't know Spanish but they are called "Interrogação" in Portuguese

Comment: Yes, Question marks sorry

Comment: My guess would be that `json_encode` breaks but I don't really see anything that would break it. Can you find out how `null` is produced?

Comment: The null is when the phrase on my query have some question marks or dots or any special character

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring the variables ($pregunta, $respuesta, $intentos, $frase) locally to the while loop, once the while loop is completed those variables no longer exist.

Change:

```
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $pregunta = $fila['pregunta'];
    $respuesta = $fila['respuesta'];
    $intentos = $fila['intentos'];
    $frase = $fila['frase'];

}

mysql_close($localhost);

$data = array('pregunta' => $pregunta, 'respuesta' => $respuesta, 'intentos' =>     $intentos, 'frase' => $frase); 
print (json_encode($data));
```

To:

```
$data = array();

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
    $pregunta = $fila['pregunta'];
    $respuesta = $fila['respuesta'];
    $intentos = $fila['intentos'];
    $frase = $fila['frase'];

    $data = array('pregunta' => $pregunta, 'respuesta' => $respuesta, 'intentos' =>     $intentos, 'frase' => $frase); 
}

mysql_close($localhost);


print (json_encode($data));
```

The data is then assigned to a variable outside the while loop and is thus retained, allowing you to output the json encoded array.

Answer (score 0):

In your java code, you can send your GET variables that way. encoded to utf-8

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("Do I need to write a question mark?", "utf-8");
 String url = "http://questionmark.com/search?q=" + query;
```